# how to wget file in directory bash .sh

Tags: bash, wget

I need to copy a file via wget command.

This is my bash script and i need to drop the file in this directory:

/home/user/public/folder/

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(/home/user/public/folder/ --file-selection --directory)
wget -O $dir/file.txt "https://www.website.com/file.txt"
```

but i cannot get the file in that directory, what is wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Now is getting teh data, but is adding a blank line after line.

```
Data1   Data1   Data1   Data1

Data2   Data2   Data2   Data2

Data3   Data3   Data3   Data3
```

the original is:

```
Data1   Data1   Data1   Data1
Data2   Data2   Data2   Data2
Data3   Data3   Data3   Data3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably because: `dir=$(/home/user/public/folder/ --file-selection --directory)` is failing.

Why don't you just use:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=/home/user/public/folder
wget -O $dir/file.txt "https://www.website.com/file.txt"
```

Comment: Hi @Adam, this is ok, but can you please tell me why is adding a new blank line after line with text? see my question